# Disabling CKEditor in comments 

Tags: 7, comments, wysiwyg

Does anyone know of a way to force plain text mode in comments for all roles?

Edit: is it in any way possible to do so through CSS? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `admin/settings/ckeditor/editg`. There you can change the visibility settings by field path (something like `content_type@path.element_id`). That should work.

Comment: What's the *editg* in `admin/settings/ckeditor/editg` ?! This takes me to the same page as `admin`

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  // comments
  // http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_form/6

  if ($form['#id'] == 'comment-form') {
    $form['comment_filter']['format'] = array(); // nuke wysiwyg from comments
  }
}
```

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance but where exactly does this function go? Thanks! Jane

Comment: This is an example of a hook that would go inside a custom module.  Though the term "custom module" may sound daunting, it is a fairly common task.  The best place to start is http://drupal.org/developing/modules

Comment: OK thanks! Will try, though yes it does sound quite daunting... :)

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 6, I would recommend the [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module to control this. It allows to set a default input format on comments, but also allows different defaults per role and per content type. The Drupal 7 version is [in development](http://drupal.org/node/815750), but its status is a bit unclear at the moment because some of the features are now in core.

Comment: Yeah I have Better Formats (it's a Drupal 6 site) but either I am using it wrong or for some reason it's failing to disable ckeditor in comments... at least for the roles that have permission to use ckeditor.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in D7. To fix it I changed the default input format of comments to Plain Text (ckeditor did not have a profile for that input format). This removed ckeditor from comments.

To remove the input format hints I installed the better formats module.

**Update:** I just noticed that your question was how to force plain text mode for all roles. To simplify I would just change the way the input format process text from "filtered text" to "plain text".

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way. I fixed input format to a non wysiwyg one and denied access of it.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_comment_form_alter().
 */
function comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$form_id) {
  $form['comment_body']['#after_build'][] = 'MYMODULE_customize_comment_form';
}

/**
 * Comment body after-build function.
 */
function MYMODULE_customize_comment_form(&$form) {
  // Hide text-format selector in comment form and fix format to filtered_html
  $form[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format']['format']['#value'] = 'filtered_html';
  $form[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```